# Getting value of a hidden field in Rails with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, hiddenfield

I have a problem in my Rails Project. It runs on Rails 2 by the way.

```
<%= form.hidden_field :foo %>
```

Is it possible to get the value of this hidden field with jQuery?
Maybe something like this:

```
var foo = jQuery('hidden_field').val();
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the ':hidden' selector in jQuery ( http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/ ).  To expand on @Koraktor's examples:

```
var foo = jQuery('#foo:hidden').val();
```

or

```
var foo = jQuery('form#some_form input[name="foo"]:hidden').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use the ID of the field (or some other unique selectors):

```
var foo = jQuery('#foo').val();
```

or

```
var foo = jQuery('form#some_form input[name="foo"]').val();
```

PS: Getting the value of a hidden is nothing different from a normal field. Hiding a field is a pure interface decision.

Answer (score 0):

A rails hidden field is identical to a rails non-hidden field.

`jQuery("[name=foo]")` will get that field.

For nested forms you can get all inputs of those sorts by `jQuery("[name $= '[foo]'")`.

There are also queries for hidden fields like `jQuery(":input:hidden")` *:input selects input, select, textarea, button vs just input elements.*.

In the end `<input type="hidden"/>` is identical to `<input type="text"/>` when it comes to name selectors or id selectors or anything.